# 2D Array vs Jagged array?

Tags: arrays, unity-game-engine, multidimensional-array, area, jagged-arrays

So, I've searched a bit, but not entirely sure what to search on, tbh...
I'm currently doing some "level generation" code, and creating objects to contain the objects for my generation.
Basically I have a "Cell" class which is defined by a Coordinate.
I'm then trying to create a "CellArea" class, which holds multiple cells in an area. It'd be simple enough if this was a rectangle, as I'd just use Cell[, ] then. But since this could be an "L" shape of sorts (I'm fine with limiting it to 2 "Corridors"), how would I go about doing that? Or is it simply more efficient to do some sort of list/collection?

I was wondering if you can do a Jagged Array that'd look something like...

```
{0, 1, 2}
{0, 1, 2}
{0, 1, 2}
{0, 1, 2}
{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

I hope I made my question clear? Obviously I could do a bidim array that is [7, 6] and then not fill in the "null" places, but isn't that inefficient in a way?

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course you can!

```
int[][] jaggedArray = new int[7][];

jaggedArray[0] = new int[] {0, 1, 2};
jaggedArray[1] = new int[] {0, 1, 2};
jaggedArray[2] = new int[] {0, 1, 2};
jaggedArray[3] = new int[] {0, 1, 2};
jaggedArray[4] = new int[] {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
jaggedArray[5] = new int[] {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
jaggedArray[6] = new int[] {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I'm taking that into consideration now :D Though I think I'm gonna start off with a bidim array actually, and then see how big our need for "odd" areas are. I'll just use 2 "CellArea"s to define a corridor with a bend :) Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Keep in mind that a contiguous array is much more efficient than an array of arrays. Additionally, jagged arrays won't help you if your map is shaped like a lower case letter "h". If you need to access this data many times in rapid succession, the slowdown from referencing man different arrays (cache-thrashing) will be worse than the memory usage from keeping the map in one big array.